# Cannot install QGIS 2.18 from repository on Debian Stretch; package "gdal-abi-2-1-1" not installable

Tags: qgis, gdal, debian

I've been using QGIS from the repository (http://qgis.org/debian/ stretch main). I tried to do an update today (it had been a while) but it could not be updated because `qgis : Depends: gdal-abi-2-1-1 but it is not installable`.

I uninstalled QGIS, switched the repository to http://qgis.org/debian-nightly-release/, and tried to reinstall, but it gave me the same error.

```
 qgis : Depends: gdal-abi-2-1-1 but it is not installable
        Depends: libqgis-analysis2.18.0 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libqgis-app2.18.0 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: python-qgis (= 1:2.18.0+git20161104+b23e29f+14stretch) but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: qgis-plugin-globe but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: qgis-plugin-grass but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: qgis-provider-grass but it is not going to be installed
```

A bit of searching shows that this package is available in sid, but not stretch.

Comment: **Same problem I also cannot install mysql-workbench
Because of:
mysql-workbench : Depends: gdal-abi-2-1-1 but it is not installable
at /etc/os-release PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux stretch/sid"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"** @debianAMD64:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
[sudo] password for ....: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/98955)

Comment: gdal-abi-2-1-2 is actually in Stretch https://packages.debian.org/stretch/virtual/gdal-abi-2-1-2, but qgis depends on gdal-abi-2-1-1. Might need to file a bug report to the QGIS package maintenance team to change that dependency.

Comment: Great. I know I have to wait that debian developers working on dhis gdal depandancy package.... Today it work fine Excelent work Debian-Developer !!!

Answer (score 14):

With *gdal-abi-2-1-2* being just a virtual package of *libgdal20*, I circumvented the problem by creating a fake *gdal-abi-2-1-2* package using *equivs-build* with the following control file:

```
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 3.9.2

Package: gdal-abi-2-1-2
Version: 2.1.2
Depends: libgdal20
Description: fake package for qgis which needs a gdal-abi-2-1-2
```

Save the code above as *gdal-abi.control*, make a fake package with *equivs-build gdal-abi.control* , then install the resulting deb package.

Now, *sudo apt install qgis qgis-plugin-grass* should work.

Comment: This indeed sorts it out for me on Mint 18.1 for QGIS 2.18.5 and GDAL 2.1.3 update problems from the Ubuntugis repos. Legend!

Answer (score 6):

Nice! I have ubuntu 14-04 and now I have a problem with the sama package in order to install the latest version of QGIS 2.18.14.

I solved installing equivs-build package

```
sudo apt-get install equivs
```

creating a text file (gdal_abi.txt) with the following text:

```
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 3.9.2

Package: gdal-abi-2-1-0
Version: 2.1.0
Depends: libgdal20
Description: fake package for qgis which needs a gdal-abi-2-1-0
```

and finally I launch:

```
sudo equivs-build gdal_abi.txt
```

in order to create the fake deb. Then I install the fake deb file (e.g. dkpg -i ...) and then I can install the latest version of QGIS!

Answer (score 0):

Debian testing and sid are always likely to have broken packages, because one software (qgis) is not packaged at the same time as another software (gdal).

GDAL has been updated from 2.1.1 to 2.1.2, but the QGIS packages at qgis.org/debian not yet. Most probably you have to wait until QGIS 2.18.1 is released.

Before updating, have a look at https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/qgis and https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/gdal to see what is available. By now, GDAL 2.1.1 has been replaced for sid as well.

In the meantime, you can install QGIS 2.14.8 from the main debian repo (without any package from qgis.org/debian)

---

**UPDATE 2016-11-28**

QGIS 2.18.1 is out now, and the qgis.org/debian stretch distro package is compiled against GDAL 2.1.2. So it should work now with the main debian repo.