# QGIS depends on gdal-abi-2.1.1 not installable

Tags: qgis, gdal, debian

I tried to install QGIS on debian sid but it depends on gdal-abi-2-1-1 that should be contained in libgdal20. But libgdal20 is already on gdal-abi-2-1-2. Is there a solution for this? Installing gdal-abi-2-1-1 or using qgis with gdal-abi-2-1-2?

Comment: It sems that you are using qgis.org/debian sid repo with the main debian sid repo. qgis.org is still at GDAL 2.1.1, while main debian is already at 2.1.2. My best advice is to remove qgis.org from your repo list, remove the packages, and install QGIS 2.14.8 solely from the main debian repo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216780/cannot-install-qgis-2-18-from-repository-on-debian-stretch-package-gdal-abi-2 (although stretch, not sid)

Comment: Thanks! Installing QGIS from the debian main repositories worked quite well.

Comment: you can now try QGIS 2.18.1 from qgis.org, compiled against GDAL 2.1.2.