# QGIS 2.18.5 update breaks on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, ubuntugis, linux-mint

Concurrent updates to GDAL (to 2.1.3) and QGIS (to 2.18.5) on Linux Mint 18.1 from the Ubuntugis repos breaks QGIS, with a noted dependency for the virtual package gdal-abi-2-1-2 being uninstallable.

The stable Ubuntugis ppa currently supplies GDAL 2.1.0 (gdal-abi-2-1-0) while the Ubuntugis-unstable ppa has been updated to GDAL 2.1.3 (gdal-abi-2-1-3).

Has anyone found a way around this?

**Update**:

QGIS bug report for those interested is here: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/16386

---

**UPDATE 2**

The ticket has been closed as fixed. Everything should be back to normal now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a bug report and not a question for GIS.SE - see https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4185/what-should-we-do-with-bug-reports This one includes a workaround as an answer but the QGIS bug report has that too.  I don't think our Q&As should be "duplicates" of a QGIS bug report.

Comment: It is fixed, QGIS 2.18.5 can be now installed with ubuntugis dependences.

Answer (score 1):

Until QGIS on the Ubuntugis repos gets built with the updated GDAL packages the easiest workaround I've found to get around this dependency issue is to create a fake virtual gdal-abi-2-1-2 package using equivs-build per the instructions here: [Cannot install QGIS 2.18 from repository on Debian Stretch; package "gdal-abi-2-1-1" not installable](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216780/cannot-install-qgis-2-18-from-repository-on-debian-stretch-package-gdal-abi-2/233830#233830)

QGIS should then update to 2.18.5 and run normally.